# Issue in writing a list to a YML file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, yaml, pyml

```
import yaml

output = [
    '{"football": "basketball"}',
    '{"basketball": "basketball" }'
]

dict_file = [
    {'sports' : output},
    {'countries' : [
        'Pakistan',
        'USA',
        'India',
        'China',
        'Germany',
        'France',
        'Spain']
    }
]

with open(r'E:\data\store_file.yaml', 'w') as file:
    documents = yaml.dump(dict_file, file)
```

Output:

```
- sports:
  - '{"football": "basketball"}'
  - '{"basketball": "basketball" }'
```

Desired output:

```
- sports:
  - {"football": "basketball"}
  - {"basketball": "basketball" }
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The YAML file accurately represents the data you've shown in your question. The variable `output` is a list of strings, not a list of dictionaries. For the desired output, you would need to fix your code:

```
output = [{"football": "basketball"}, {"basketball": "basketball" }]
```

Note that this will give you:

```
- sports:
  - football: basketball
  - basketball: basketball
```

Which is syntactically identical to:

```
- sports:
  - {"football": "basketball"}
  - {"basketball": "basketball" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing strings in `output`

Remove the single quotes to make them dictionaries:

```
output = [{"football": "basketball"}, {"basketball": "basketball" }]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What if I have output like below?

output = ['i prefer a [football]{"xyz": "sports", "val": "health"} than basketball']

Answer (score 0):

ultimately, this can work for you

```
import yaml
import json
output = ['{"football": "basketball"}', '{"basketball": "basketball" }']
dict_file = [{'sports' : [json.loads(_) for _ in output]},
{'countries' : ['Pakistan', 'USA', 'India', 'China', 'Germany', 'France', 'Spain']}]

with open(r'E:\data\store_file.yaml', 'w') as file:
    documents = yaml.dump(dict_file, file)
```

`.yml` file:

```yaml
    - sports:
      - football: basketball
      - basketball: basketball
    - countries:
      - Pakistan
      - USA
      - India
      - China
      - Germany
      - France
      - Spain
```

For your information, the `dict` structure will not come with `{}` brackets in the `.yml`. It will be without brackets and when reading you can read as a keys & values(`Dict`) type.

**Note**: Updated the answer and thanks for suggesting `@accdias`

Comment: Instead of `eval()`, I guess `json.loads()` is a safer alternative. Something like this will do the job: `{'sports': [json.loads(_) for _ in output]}`.

Comment: @accdias, you are 100% right.

Comment: @accdias I have updated the answer with your suggestion and yes, it is the safest method to implement.

Comment: Nice. You are missing an `import json` in your answer though. :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I added that too.